# Azure DevOps Principal is not Showing Up in Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) document, im trying to consume secrets in my key vault when i design my YAML template on my CI pipeline, but when i go to key vault, add access policies, select principal, i cannot find my principal, it simply says "No result found."

This is the step where I'm stuck at
[image]

my project name is `PoC-One`
my devops account name is `Home-PoC`
subscription id is `XXXXX`
so my principal should have been `Home-PoC-PoC-One-XXXXX` right?

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

go to project settings -> service connection -> select ur service connection -> edit -> copy the WHOLE subscription ID -> paste the whole subscription ID in the select a principal search box in key vault when adding access policies -> you should find it then click add

Comment: hi @JaneMa-MSFT i dont know if you actually work for MSFT or not but could you please add that to the official azure docs? i'm sure someone in the future will have the same issue as that part is not mentioned at all, you dont even have to give me credit, just put in there for someone to read